# R Shiny dplyr multi select for filter error when using src_postgres

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, dplyr

A little app to filter sales by company

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(DT)

company=c("A","L","S","T","W","A","L","S","T","W")
sales=c(120,140,160,180,200,120,140,160,180,200)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$theCustomersList <- renderUI({
    list(
      selectInput("customer", "Choose a customer:",
                   c("A","L","S","T","W")
                   ,selectize=FALSE
                   ,multiple=TRUE
                   ,selected="A"
                   )
        )})

  output$result <- DT::renderDataTable(data_frame(company,sales) %>% filter(company%in%input$customer))
    }

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("theCustomersList")
    ),


    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('result'))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This works OK as is but if I change it to use a postgresql table as the source of the sales data using src_postgresql I get an error if I only select a single company from the dropdown.

Basically the SQL generated gives the following

```
Error: RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'A'" LINE 4: ... AND "company" IN 'A'
```

Anybody with any ideas?

Update.... this is definitely a database issue. When the filter is applied to an in memory dataframe the "%in%" construct works with either a single selection or multiple selections. When applied to the postgres source the brackets are missed off the resulting sql meaning that the SQL is malformed.

```
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'A'"
LINE 3: WHERE "company" IN 'A'
```

Comment: Please post your sql command. The error seems to be related to sql only and not related to shiny.

Comment: Hi... I'm not generating the SQL but from the error I think its generating "company" IN ("A","L") for multiple selections and "company" IN "A" for a single - that is, it is missing out the brackets.

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251927/how-to-filter-a-remote-table-based-on-one-single-value/38298875#38298875

Comment: Closing because solutions are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591084/multiple-selectinput-values-create-unexpected-dplyr-postgres-behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251927/how-to-filter-a-remote-table-based-on-one-single-value