# How to filter a remote table based on one single value?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing a `filter()` using `%in%` but the way dplyr translates the query seems incorrect. In fact, the `%in%` operator works fine with more than one value, but it doesn't when only a single element is present.
In my original scenario the filtering values are dynamic, thus I would like to have a function that works in both cases.

```
my_db <- src_mysql(dbname = "dplyr", 
                   host = "dplyr.csrrinzqubik.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 
                   port = 3306, 
                   user = "dplyr",
                   password = "dplyr")
tbl(my_db, "dplyr") %>% filter(carrier %in% c("UA","AA")) #works
tbl(my_db, "dplyr") %>% filter(carrier %in% c("UA")) #doesn't work
```

My question is a duplicate of [multiple selectInput values create unexpected dplyr (postgres) behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591084/multiple-selectinput-values-create-unexpected-dplyr-postgres-behavior). Seems like [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2010) is well-known too

Comment: What version of dplyr? The SQL translation structure changed in 0.5.0.

Comment: @alistaire I was using 4.3, now I have updated but the problem is still there.

Comment: could you hack around this by using `... %in% c("Art","some_absent_junk")`?  (unsatisfactory, but maybe useful as a workaround)

Comment: @BenBolker alright, I was just wondering if I was missing something. I thought this sort of operation to be so common that it was unlikely to present a bug.

Comment: well, this is not a set of tools (or more particularly a corner of this package) that I use regularly, so I don't really know.  Hopefully someone with more knowledge will dig in and give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting together some of the suggestions, the best approach for my scenario it's probably gonna be the one below. The reason why I don't like nesting the `filter()` in a `if` statement, is that I have multiple `filter` from menu items of a shiny app. Thus, manipulating the variable at the source saves me a lot of typing.

```
a <- c("UA")
b <- if(length(a)>1) a else c(a,"")
tbl(my_db, "dplyr") %>% 
  filter(carrier %in% b)
```

Or

```
 a <- c("UA")
 varToFilterFor <- rep(a ,2)
tbl(my_db, "dplyr") %>% 
      filter(carrier %in% varToFilterFor)
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't offer any insights into why your code fails. But until someone can provide a better solution, here is a simple work-around that provides "a function that works in both cases".

```
my.carriers <- c("UA","AA")
my.carriers <- c("UA")

if (length(my.carriers)>1) {
  tbl(my_db, "dplyr") %>% filter(carrier %in% my.carriers)
} else {
  tbl(my_db, "dplyr") %>% filter(carrier == my.carriers)
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what was suggested in the link I have added to my question. I am considering `ifelse()` too, but I am not sure whether it would be equivalent in terms of performance.

Comment: I tried `ifelse` as my 1st attempt - I could not get it to work. it does not seem to wait for reply to query for some reason

Comment: It's probably due to the vectorization of `ifelse` which "returns a value with the same shape as test". This example helped me to understand why it doesn't work `d <- c("AA","AA","EV","DL")
a <- c("UA","AA")
ifelse(length(a)>1, d %in% a, d == a)
if(length(a)>1) {d %in% a} else {d==a}`